# How to allow the browser to redirect to another page when clicked on each of a country in the map?

Tags: html, redirect, d3.js, onclick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 World Map</title>
<style>
    .country:hover {
        fill: #52adcc;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    .text {
        font-size:10px;
        text-transform:capitalize;
    }
    #container {
        margin:10px 10%;
        border:2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        background: #F0F8FF;
    }
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    div.tooltip {
        color: #222;
        background: #fff;
        padding: .5em;
        text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #a6a6a6;
        opacity: 0.9;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .graticule {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #bbb;
        stroke-width: .5px;
        stroke-opacity: .5;
    }
    .equator {
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 1px;
    }
    .country {
        fill: #cccccc;
        border: 10px yellow;
    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>World Map</h1>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="Javascripts/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascripts/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascripts/datamaps.world.js"></script>
    <script>
        d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);

        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 9])
            .on("zoom", move);


        var width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
        var height = width / 2;

        var topo, projection, path, svg, g;

        var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

        var tooltip = d3.select("#container").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip hidden");

        setup(width, height);

        function setup(width, height) {
            projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                .translate([(width / 2), (height / 2)])
                .scale(width / 2 / Math.PI);

            path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

            svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .call(zoom)
                .on("click", click)
                .append("g");

            g = svg.append("g");

        }

        d3.json("Json/world-topo-min.json", function(error, world) {

            var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

            topo = countries;
            draw(topo);

        });

        function draw(topo) {

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(graticule)
                .attr("class", "graticule")
                .attr("d", path);


            g.append("path")
                .datum({
                type: "LineString",
                coordinates: [
                    [-180, 0],
                    [-90, 0],
                    [0, 0],
                    [90, 0],
                    [180, 0]
                ]
            })
                .attr("class", "equator")
                .attr("d", path);


            var country = g.selectAll(".country").data(topo);


            country.enter().insert("path")
                .attr("class", "country")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("id", function(d, i) {
                return d.id;
            })
                .attr("title", function(d, i) {
                return d.properties.name;
            });
            //.style("fill", function(d, i) { return d.properties.color; });

            //offsets for tooltips
            var offsetL = document.getElementById('container').offsetLeft + 20;
            var offsetT = document.getElementById('container').offsetTop + 10;

            //tooltips
            country.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {

                var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map(function(d) {
                    return parseInt(d);
                });

                tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
                    .attr("style", "left:" + (mouse[0] + offsetL) + "px;top:" + (mouse[1] + offsetT) + "px")
                    .html(d.properties.name);

            })
                .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
                tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
            });

            country.click().


            //EXAMPLE: adding some capitals from external CSV file
            d3.csv("Json/country-capitals.csv", function(err, capitals) {

                capitals.forEach(function(i) {
                    addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude, i.CapitalName);
                });

            });

        }

        function redraw() {
            width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
            height = width / 2;
            d3.select('svg').remove();
            setup(width, height);
            draw(topo);
        }


        function move() {

            var t = d3.event.translate;
            var s = d3.event.scale;
            zscale = s;
            var h = height / 4;


            t[0] = Math.min(
            (width / height) * (s - 1),
            Math.max(width * (1 - s), t[0]));

            t[1] = Math.min(
            h * (s - 1) + h * s,
            Math.max(height * (1 - s) - h * s, t[1]));

            zoom.translate(t);
            g.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");

            //adjust the country hover stroke width based on zoom level
            d3.selectAll(".country").style("stroke-width", 1.5 / s);

        }

        var throttleTimer;

        function throttle() {
            window.clearTimeout(throttleTimer);
            throttleTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
                redraw();
            }, 200);
        }


        //geo translation on mouse click in map
        function click() {
            var latlon = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
            console.log(latlon);
        }
    </script>
    <!-- <a class="country" href="#" onclick="window.open('worldmap-template.html')"></a> -->
</body>

</html>
```

I want to be able to redirect to a link that is specific for each of the country by using an onclick function but I have tried using numerous methods but there were no response. Hope that you guys will be able to help me out in this as I am unsure of what methods to be call to allow the onclick function to be able to function properly after selecting one of the country and clicking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hooked up USA and Canada here:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://plungjan.name/eetest/testmap.html)

On the [starter kit](http://techslides.com/d3-map-starter-kit/) you seem to use, you have this code

```
//tooltips
  country
    .on("mousemove", function(d,i) {

      var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map( function(d) { return parseInt(d); } );

      tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
             .attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+offsetL)+"px;top:"+(mouse[1]+offsetT)+"px")
             .html(d.properties.name);

      })
      .on("mouseout",  function(d,i) {
        tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
      }); // <---- remove this semicolon

     // add this

     .on("click",function(d,i) {
       var myPage = myPages[d.properties.name];
       location=myPage?myPage:"noPageForCountry.html"
     });
```

Comment out the click handler:

```
 svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom)
 // .on("click", click)
    .append("g");
```

Then change

```
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);
```

to

```
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);
var myPages = {"United States":"usa.html", "Canada":"canada.html"}
```

and add whatever countries you want to the list so they match the title you have onmouseover